# Numbering occurrences within groups in python

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe with information about students and test dates. I would like to create a variable that takes on a new value for each student, but also takes on a new value for the same student if 5 years have passed without a test attempt. The desired column is "group" below. How can I do this in python?

```
Student test_date group 
Bob     1995      1
Bob     1997      1   
Bob     2020      2 
Bob     2020      2
Mary    2020      3
Mary    2021      3
Mary    2021      3
```

The initial, very clunky idea I had was to sort by name, sort by date, calculate the difference in date, have an ind if diff > 5, and then somehow number by groups.

```
    ds = pd.read_excel('../students.xlsx')
    ds = ds.sort_values(by=['student','test_date'])
    ds['time'] = ds['test_date'].diff() 
    ds['break'] = 0 
    ds.loc[(ds['time'] > 5),'break'] = 1
```

```
Student test_date time break
Bob     1995     na     na
Bob     1997     2      0
Bob     2020     23     1
Bob     2020     0      0
Mary    2020     na     na
Mary    2021     1      0
Mary    2021     0      0
```

Comment: Can you provide example output?

Comment: The "group" on the right is the desired output so given "student" and "test" date I am struggling to generate "group"

Comment: what have you tried?  post some code

Comment: What is your input format? List? Pandas Dataframe? Spark Dataframe? Text? CSV? Something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help attract quality answers if you [edi]t your question to include a [mcve] with sample input, expected output, and code for what you've already tried based on your own research, as well as a description of what went wrong with your attempts. As it stands, it's not clear what you're asking for, and the section you posted with code formatting is not valid python

Comment: So you're iterating over some data... is the data already ordered by `test_date`?  That will make it easier.  You will need a var to keep track of the last `test_date` seen for each student, then when you come to output the `group` value you can increment it based on the difference between last seen `test_date` and the value for the current row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.sort_values(["Student", "test_date"])
((df.Student != df.Student.shift()) | (df.test_date.diff().gt(5))).cumsum()
# 0    1
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    2
# 4    3
# 5    3
# 6    3
# dtype: int32
```